# Node EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 when testing with jest and supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to test my API endpoints with jest and supertest:

my test routes file:

```
const app = require('../../index') 
const request = require('supertest')


describe('test app endpoints', ()=>{
    test('index should return 200 code', async (done) =>{
        const response = await request(app).get('/')
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
        done()
    })
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

const port = 3000


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/', require('./routes/conversions'))

module.exports = app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

When I run this test I get error about occupied port:

> ```
> listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
> ```

How can I fix that and do not block my port for tests?

Comment: Use a different port? You really shouldn't use port numbers lower than 8000 or so.

Comment: I tried to change my port number to something else and I get the same error but with the new port number.

Comment: Is it trying to spin up your app multiple times? Because that isn't going to work....

Answer (score 14):

This issue is actually with the way you are running the server in the testing environment.
A simple fix for this issue is wrapping app.listen() in a condition to check if the environment is a test environment or not. In a test environment, when running the server through Supertest, you don't need to have the app listen on a network port.
So fix this by adding a conditional check to index.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    app.listen(port);
}
```

for more read [this](https://blog.campvanilla.com/jest-expressjs-and-the-eaddrinuse-error-bac39356c33a)

Comment: then what would the module export

Comment: @stackers when running the server through test, you don't need to have the app listen on a network port.

Answer (score 0):

Something else on your computer is using port 3000; that's all. Just set the `port` variable to something else; 8080 and 8000 are popular choices.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an issue since "lsof -i :3000" returns no other programs running on that port. I belive it's a problem with jest or supertests and they run those ports multiple times. I tried to change my port number to something else and I get the same error but with the new port number.

Comment: Just to confirm, the code works when you run `node index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid calling `app.listen()` when you run tests. While wrapping `app.listen()` in an `if` statement works, you can also organize your code like this:

```
// app.ts

import express from 'express'
import { router } from './router'

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api', router)
// more setup here...

export { app }
```

```
// index.ts or server.ts

import { app } from './app'

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port 3000`)
})
```

Then in your tests import `app` from `app.ts`, which avoids the `EADDRINUSE` issue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807079/4034572) adds a bit more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux then you can use `ss`.

Say for example your port which is already bound to by another application is `3000`, then you can use the following command to list all the applications which are currently either bound/ have an open socket listening from the port `3000` :-

`ss -ap | grep 3000`

You'll be also shown the name of the processes along with their `pid`.

Take a note of the process id of the process which is no longer needed, and then run a `kill -9 PID` to get rid of it.

You'll need to get rid of the process which is bound to the port `3000` to be able to launch a new process which binds to it.

Only one process at most can bind itself to a port on a machine.